# Removing extra space from the bottom so that everything aligns in one line

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a header right now, and as you can see on the [demo](http://cssdeck.com/labs/mf2cpoaq) there is to much black space on the bottom which makes the language button go down compared to the rest of the text.

**EDIT**

I added a border in `li` and you can see some boxes underneath the text. I think that's causing the text not to align and making unnecessary space.

Is there any way I can move/remove those boxes?

Comment: The images in your demo link don't work which makes is hard to help.  You can use this site to make placeholder images: http://placehold.it/

Comment: I edited the demo now with placeholder

Comment: If you add a border to the `li`s, you can see that it isn't the language button that is in the wrong place.

Comment: @AdamZuckerman is there any way i can move those boxes in `li` ?

Comment: Yes. You need to play with your positioning.

Comment: Hmm, I would appreciate if you could make a post about it, i'm not sure what to add and if i need to do it in the `li` or somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the title my understanding is you want the align the text and image inside the `li`

you have to remove extra padding from `img` and `p` .

```
.left-content ul li img {
    bottom: -9px;
    padding: 12px 5px 10px 3px; /*Remove this line.*/
    position: relative;
}
.left-content ul li p {
    bottom: 17px; /*Remove this line.*/
    display: inline;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative; /*Remove this unnecessary line.*/
}
```

Here is the Demo. http://jsbin.com/xoyosimo/1

Answer (score 0):

Use sticky footer JS plugin. It allows to let your content stick to bottom.